# auto restart a Tika server

Tags: apache-tika

I am building a web service where users submit pdf files and from these files the content in text is extracted using `Tika`. I am using `Tika` in server mode on the same machine that I host my `Django` website.

My question is, is there a way to automate the restart of the `Tika` server when it shuts down for any reason? How can I build a script and run this so whenever the `Tika` server goes down this gets traced and the server restarts again? My ultimate goal for this is not to check every day from the console if `Tika` is down, neither to realize that the service is down when a user complains that her pdf does get extracted.

Comment: What platform are you running on? Windows? Linux? Mac? BSD? Other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using a recent copy of Ubuntu, your easiest option is probably to create a custom Upstart job for it. On other unixes, you'd want something similar for their init system, and on Windows I think something with [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) to wrap it as a Windows service is likely the best bet.

As [covered in this post over on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62434/why-does-upstart-keep-respawning-my-process), the key thing you'll want is the `respawn` option, to tell upstart to re-launch the Tika server if it happens to fail, and a limit in case it gets really broken for some reason.

You'll want to create a file `/etc/init/tika-server.conf`, with contents along the lines of:

```
description     "Apache Tika Server"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 3 12

exec java -jar /path/to/tika/tika-server-1.10-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Tweak the path to your Tika Server jar, and add any options / parameters you want to the end.

With that done, to `init-checkconf /etc/init/tika-server.conf` to check it's valid, then `service tika-server start` to start it.

At that point, you can head to `http://localhost:9998/` and see it running! If it dies, upstart will restart it for you.